# Streamlit + Panda Dataframe: Change the way date gets displayed

Tags: pandas, streamlit

I am using streamlit to render a padas dataframe with st.table(dataframe). Right now dates in the dataframe get displayed like this:

https://ibb.co/dKq2KQm

I would like to display it in this way: 2020-12-30 00:30,
is there any way to change this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [pandas styler](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html) and python's [strftime method](https://strftime.org/) to achieve what you need.

This is an example:

```py
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07'],
                   'goal': [4, 2.1, 5.9],
                   'actual': [8, 5.1, 7.7]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.style.format({'date': lambda x: "{}".format(x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))}).set_table_styles('styles')

st.dataframe(df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works, as a sidenote, I was using this table to retrieve and manipulate data. This doesn't work because a styled data row, differs from the others. To avoid that, I duplicated the dataframe.